# Segmentation fault when using circular doubly linked list of strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that takes as command line arguments: the name of the file to be parsed and a set of delimiters. The program should tokenize the file into substrings delimited by the chars mentioned as argv[2]. Then, I need to add the substrings into a circular doubly linked list and print it in reverse order. The first part works fine, I just need some help regarding the second one (I'm still kind of new to linked lists). My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1024


typedef struct node{
    char token[MAX];
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}node;

void insert_beginning(node **tail ,char *value)
{
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(new_node->token, value);
    new_node->prev = NULL;
    new_node->next = *tail;
    if(*tail == NULL)
    {
        (*tail)->prev = new_node;
    }
    (*tail)->prev = new_node;
    *tail = new_node;
}

void init(node **tail, node **head, char *value) // use this first to initialize the 1st member
{
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error at memory allocation\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(new_node->token, value);
    new_node->prev = NULL;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    *tail = new_node;
    *head = new_node;   
}

void deallocate(node **tail, node **head)
{
    if(*tail == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    node *curr = *tail;
    while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
        free(curr->prev);
    }
    free(curr);

    *tail = NULL;
    *head = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!fin)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid format.\nCorrect usage: %s filename.c ''token_list''\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buf[MAX];
    char delim[MAX];
    char *fields[MAX];
    strcpy(delim, argv[2]);
//  size_t len = strlen(delim);
    printf("%s\n", delim);
/*  printf("The tokens are:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", delim[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');*/

    node *tail = NULL;
    node *head = NULL;

    while(fgets(buf, MAX, fin))
    {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  // strip the trailing newline
        char *token = strtok(buf, delim);
        for (int j = 0; token; ++j)
        {
            fields[j] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            printf("%s\n", fields[j]);
        } 
    }
    init(&tail, &head, fields[0]); //  first initialize the 1st element of the list then the rest
    for(int i = 1; *fields; i++)
    {
        insert_beginning(&tail, fields[i]);
    }
    for(node *curr = tail; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
    {
        printf("%s\n", curr->token);
    }    

    deallocate(&tail, &head);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the file:

```
Lorem, ipsum;
 dolor/
.
sit/ amet.
```

For the command lines: `./a.out parse_test.c ";./"`  , the output is:

```
Lorem, ipsum
 dolor
sit
 amet
```

and then a seg fault. Any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: The array `*fields[MAX]` stores the token pointers *for each line* (index `j` starts at `0` for each line) but then processes those of the *last* line. Yet the following loop `for(int i = 1; *fields; i++)` is testing an element that might not have been set in the last line, and may not now even be valid data (was overwritten). Not sure what the intention is. What is the condition `*fields;` supposed to do? Even if it was intnded to be `fields[i];` it may still be checking (by now) invalid pointers from previous lines that contained more tokens than the last line.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, I think I should declare ```j = 0``` outside the while, and replace the for loop with a while and update j++ at the end of it. ```*fields``` was supposed to check if we have anything different from NULL

Comment: A *debugger* would tell you at *least* where the cart finally went off the road. from there you should be able to deduce when the wheels actually left prior.

Comment: `*fields` will have the same value on each iteration of the loop, so can't be used as an end test.

Comment: Why have `fields` at all? It's only used to construct the list. Why not construct the list from the line buffer token directly? Inside your `while` loop, in the first `for` loop, just replace: `fields[j] = token;` with `insert_beginning(&tail, token);` You can eliminate the second `for` loop altogether.